# Cannot edit files on RPi through smb

Tags: pi-2, samba

I Just set up my RPi as a samba server. I connected it to my Mac through samba and can browse files on it, but it said that I did not have permissions. I went to the RPi and changed to the folder to `777`. I still didn't get access. I created a samba user on my RPi and connected to it using that user, but it didn't work. Do I need to change any permissions on my mac?

(I am okay with using `sshfs` because I only need to access one directory, but the tutorial on the Raspberry Pi website was slightly unclear)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sharing files on an external disk? If so, what filesystem is it formatted with? NTFS volumes can only be mounted with a single "owner". If the volume is mounted by root, connecting users will not be able to write to the filesystem, no matter what you do with Samba. Either reformat the filesystem with one that allows full linux user permissions (I use ext4) or mount NTFS with your (single) user as the owner.

Other than that, it would be helpful if you shared additional details on the filesystem, and the relevant portions of your Samba configuration. By default, user home directories should be accessible, assuming the user account can write to the filesystem.